# How to open a file in a list of files in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a longish list of files opened in vim that looks like this:

```
/dir1/file1
/dir2/file2
/dir2/file3
.....
```

How can I open all of them one by one the easiest way possible in the same session of vim either with split or edit?

Comment: You are saying "I have them opened", then asking "How can I open them?"
If it's the former, Paul Tomblin's answer is for you - :n and :prev

Comment: Or is it the actual list you have given that is open in Vim?

Comment: just curious, but why is this community wiki?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I'd say with -p for tabs

```
vim -p `cat yourlistoffiles`
```

Comment: Note that if you want to open the files in separate buffers without using vim tabs, you can remove the `-p` flag.

Comment: Also, if you do use `-p` for tabs, the number of tabs that will be opened will be limited to `tabpagemax` (10 by default). If you want to change this to 100 (for example), you can add `set tabpagemax=100` to your vimrc or set it elsewhere.

Answer (score 23):

You can use quickfix mode, as following

```
:set errorformat=%f
:cf myfilelist
```

at this point you can use the normal quickfix shortcuts to go through your files, `:cn` for the next file, `:cp` for the previous one and `:cr` to go to the first again.

**EDIT:**

oh, if you want to read the list from the current buffer, use `:cb` instead of `:cf` in in the instructions above

Comment: This seems like the best solution to me when the number of files is large. Could set up an alias like: vim -o ':set errorformat=%f' -o ':cf myfilelist'

Comment: @RandyProctor say I want to use `hg st -n` as my filelist, how would I do that?

Answer (score 10):

You can do the following

```
cat file | xargs vim
```

Where "file" contains your list of files, this will open the files in the same vim session. As usual when opening multiple buffers, you can navigate forward with :bn and backward :bp.

Comment: ..Unless the number of files is greater than xargs's split threshold, in which case you'll get multiple vim sessions.

Comment: Using xargs you can handle tens of thousands of files, are you suggesting typing these one by one on the command line like you have suggested, this seems a lot less practical.

Comment: @ng, you don't understand xargs at all.  If you pass "tens of thousands of files" to it, it will issue the vim command for the first 20, then issue another vim command for the second 20, and so on.

Comment: This answer has the advantage that it handle file name with space in it

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has any upvotes. I did this pretty often (and again right now to make certain). It does not work with VI as VI cannot see the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to assume you have the file list open inside Vim, and want to simulate the "gf" command across the whole list...

Edit your .vimrc to include this function:

```
function Openall()
    edit <cfile>
    bfirst
endfunction
```

You can then highlight the entire file (or the set of paths you want to open) using visual mode (1G, Shift-V, G) and typing ":call Openall()". Afterwards the command row will show this:

```
:'<,'>call Openall()
```

This will run the new Openall() function across all highlighted lines.

Press Enter and all the files will be opened in background buffers. You can then access them using the usual buffer commands. :ls will display them as a list.

Answer (score 7):

For my use case, where you already have a buffer open with the list of files in it, I have found the best way to do this.  You can type this in vim cmd mode:

```
:% normal gf<C-v><C-o>
```

(where `<C-v>` is you literally typing Ctrl and v, same for `<C-o>`)

and it becomes:

```
:% normal gf^O
```

#### How this works:

- `%` runs the command for every line in the file
- `normal` runs everything after it in normal mode
- `gf` opens the file under the cursor in a new buffer
- `<C-v>` lets you enter a control-code (`<C-o>` in this case)
- `<C-o>` goes back to the last location, which will always be this buffer with the list of files

#### Potential usage:

```
# open buffer with list of files from grep
$ grep -rl "new User()" mycode/ libraries/ | vim -

# then runs this in vim:
:% normal gf^O
```

#### Bonus: Make a keyboard shortcut

Add the following to your `~/.vimrc` :

```
" Open all files in current buffer (e.g. after piping to `vim -`)
nnoremap <leader>oa :% normal gf^O<cr>
```

This maps `\oa` to run the command (since `<leader>` is `\` for me).

### An alternate method using a macro:

```
qogf<C-o>j
```

which runs `gf` (go file) then uses `<C-o>` to get back to the initial unnamed buffer, then just goes down one line with `j`, ready to be repeated.

Then see how many lines in the buffer (12) and run the macro like this:

```
12@o
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want to select and list in **vim**. all the files of a certain extension. From your home directory or a particular source.

```
find . -name "*.sh" | vim -
```

Then within vim, you could search and view this potentially huge list.
(Another topic)

You found your file, now you want to open it in a split?

```
CTRL-W F                        *CTRL-W_F*
    Split current window in two.  Edit file name under cursor and
    jump to the line number following the file name. See |gF| for
    details on how the line number is obtained.
    {not available when the |+file_in_path| feature was disabled
    at compile time}


CTRL-W gf                       *CTRL-W_gf*
    Open a new tab page and edit the file name under the cursor.
    Like "tab split" and "gf", but the new tab page isn't created
    if the file does not exist.
    {not available when the |+file_in_path| feature was disabled
    at compile time}
```

Answer (score 2):

I often need to open a changing list of files that had been modified in my SVN checkout.
This one liner works to open all modified files in vim tabs.

```
svn st | grep ^M | awk "{print($2)}" | xargs vim -p
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with bash:

```
$ vim -S <(sed "s/^/badd /" <your file name>)
```

But I don't know why the first line of the file is ignored... :-O

This script works as expected:

```
rm -f myfile
for i in `seq 10000`
do
  touch $i
  echo $i >> myfile
done
vi -c "badd `head -1 myfile`" -S <(sed "s/^/badd /" myfile)
```

---

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-S
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bad

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as typing

```
vim /dir1/file1 /dir2/file1 /dir2/file2 ...
```

Once you're in vim, you can switch betwen then with ":n" to go to the next file, ":prev" to go to the previous file.

Comment: This is not what was asked, the question is how to open a long list of files.

Comment: @ng, the question is exceptionally ambiguous.

Comment: Well I googled exactly for this and landed here, so maybe the question is really ambiguous, but thanks for floating my boat.

Answer (score 0):

My [searchInRuntime](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/searchInRuntime) plugin has a :Sp and a :Vsp commands that'll do the trick when called banged. However, the files have to exist.