# To open files in Grep's output to Vim's -o -mode

Tags: vim

**How can you put a list of files to Vim's -o -mode?**

I have a list of files as Grep's output.
I run unsuccessfully

## 1

```
grep -il sid * | vim -o
```

## 2

```
grep -il sid * | xargs vim -o
```

## 3

```
grep -il sid * | xargs vim
```

## 4

```
vim -o `grep -il sid *`
```

## 5

```
vim -o | grep -il sid *
```

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/336016

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Second one works for me. Third too, although you get only one file visible at the start. 4 is the same as 2 in most cases. First and last should not work by design.

Comment: I cannot understand what was a problem in my Zsh. The commands work similarly for me now.

Comment: Funny, I use zsh too. So something must have went very bad for you for a moment :-)

Comment: This causes the dreaded `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal` error, after which the terminal is basically unusable until recovering with `stty sane`. See https://superuser.com/q/336016.

Answer (score 39):

Try

```
vim -p `grep -il sid *`
```

if you want to open the files in different tabs in the same window.

Comment: This should be marked the answer in my opinion. Does exactly what is expected without extra work.

Comment: This was the best solution for me. Using xargs in my terminal was glitchy and would only work the first time, but not the second or third time.

Comment: this works for me except, in my case, it's necessary to add 'r' to the '-il' (so '-ilr') in order to recurse down in the directories below the current one.

Comment: a nice version of this is to use `-O` with vim to open vertical columns. vim -O `grep -il <pattern> *`

Comment: This doesn't work if any of the files contain spaces.

Answer (score 30):

Run:

```
grep -il sid * | vim -
```

This tell vim to read the file from stdin, so the output of grep will be in vim.
Now, put cursor on file and press **gF** - this will open the file on the line grep indicated.

You can also use **^WF** to open file in a new split.

Comment: This works even for file names containing spaces and is easy to remember.

Comment: After opening the buffer with the filelist like that, you can then run `:% normal gf<C-v><C-o>` to automatically open all of them in new buffers.  See my answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743457/5964556

Answer (score 14):

Sorry I'm late. Some of these options work for me but with weird side effects. Try this:

```
vim -o $(grep -il sid *)
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, all the other answer complain that the input is not from a terminal. After that my terminal is hosed.

Comment: This solution fails on spaces and comes with security issues.

Comment: this works for me except, in my case, it's necessary to add 'r' to the '-il' (so '-ilr') in order to recurse down in the directories below the current one.

Comment: This causes the dreaded `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal` error, after which the terminal is basically unusable until recovering with `stty sane`. See https://superuser.com/q/336016.

Answer (score 5):

To invoke `vim` using `xargs`, `xargs` must be invoked with `-o`:

```
grep -il sid * | xargs -o vim -o
```

In case filenames could contain spaces, use `grep -Z` with `xargs -0`

```
grep -ilZ sid * | xargs -0 -o vim -o
```

Without `xargs -o`, we would get a warning:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

The `-o` option exists on OSX/BSD. Also, the `-o` option is found in  [GNU findutils built from git](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git). This option was added after 4.6.0.

Comment: `-o` only exists on OSX/BSD.

Comment: the option has also been added to GNU findutils but not released yet. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Update: [GNU findutils 4.7.0](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tag/?h=v4.7.0) released.

Answer (score 0):

The second one should work unless some of those filenames contain whitespace.  You should do

```
grep -il sid * | xargs -d "\n" vim -o
```

if this is a possibility.  `-d "\n"` tells xargs to use a newline as the delimiter when reading in the arguments; normally it is any whitespace (newline, tab, or space character)

Comment: This causes the dreaded `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal` error, after which the terminal is basically unusable until recovering with `stty sane`. See https://superuser.com/q/336016.