# After doing grep and passing it to vim then quitting, why am I experiencing this weird console malfunctioning?

Tags: bash, vim, console, ssh, grep

I tried this just now:

```
grep -RlI "id=\"kw\"" * | xargs vim
```

That gave me 16 results. It opened the first result in Vim. I made my very first edit and hit `:q` since I didn't know the shortcut to jump to the next file.

It threw me back to the console ( I am SSHed in to a server ). My console is messed up now. Anything I type I can't see, and anytime I hit enter it seems like it processes the command but the display/view is screwed up so

`[meder@linode]` is tabbed in on my console, at least halfway. `reset` does nothing since it seems to have messed up my real console.

Can anyone offer a solution that doesn't have this same downside? Or can anyone provide an explanation for why `:q`ing out of the very first file messed up my console?

**Background information**: My PC is <del>Debian</del> Ubuntu, I am SSHed into a RHEL box. The files I opened were text/ascii files phtml/php files and not some weird binary files with crazy characters in them.

Here's a [screenshot](http://static.arounds.org/Screenshot-9.png) of what happened

EDIT #1: I just typed `reset` again and it seemed to work. The first `reset` did not work I think because somehow the console inserted some whitespaceish character inside it? Anyways, I would like an explanation for this weird behaviour.

Comment: Possible dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275241/to-open-files-in-greps-output-to-vims-o-mode

Comment: @noodl - I am experiencing an issue after I `:q` which is not present in that question.

Comment: sorry for those two stupid comments. have you tried `clear` command?

Comment: `reset` worked after I typed it twice. I am wondering *why* this happens, though.

Comment: maybe it is caused by unnecessary invisible symbols like `\t` and others..? =)

Comment: 'unnecessary' meaning they are such for you =)

Comment: *Waits for the super *nix guru knight in shining armor to provide an explanation*

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
vim -o `grep -RlI "id=\"kw\"" * `
```

Comment: This command works, although it creates a set of windows within for as many files that are returned by grep when used with the -o option. This is useful for 3 or 4 files, but when I ran with a search which returned 22 files - this doesn't seem to work quite well. So I just removed the -o, and now vim opens all files sequentially :)

Answer (score 2):

From the man page for `xargs`:

```
     Undefined behavior may occur if utility reads from the standard input.
```

That line isn't in the Linux man page but it is present on my Mac. If you want to run a program that you intend to read standard input, the usual linux version of xargs will need an argument to read its input from a file:

```
   OPTIONS
       --arg-file=file, -a file
              Read items from file instead of standard input.
              If you use this option, stdin remains unchanged
              when commands are run.  Otherwise, stdin is
              redirected from /dev/null.
```

Vim is intended to run with both standard input and standard output connected to real (a very rare case these days) or pseudo tty devices. Wierd things will happen if you upset this arrangement.

The fundamental problem with your command was that, with standard input redirected to the pipe, xargs had no way to run a vim with a "normal" standard input. So the vim mode changes and command input were not what you expected.

You can probably fix this by typing a return, a tilde, and a period. This will force your ssh session closed from your end, you can then ssh in again, and run "ps" to check for anything left hung in the background that you should kill(1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:next` or `:n` to get to the next file to edit. You can also use `vim -o` to open up all the matching files in different windows in Vim.

Not sure why your console is messed up though. I tried using your command and my console was fine.

Comment: I just did `vim -o` and since all those files opened in one vim instance I didn't have to `:q` until I was done. After I was done though, the same issue came up.

Answer (score 1):

Console options are set by `stty`, so you may want to save its options to a bash variable and restore them after vim exits, like this:

```
function vim()
{
    STTYOPTS="$(stty --save)"
    vim "$@"
    stty "${STTYOPTS}"
}
```

But it is probably the better way to use zsh for this task: if you put the only line `ttyctl -f` into your `~/.zshrc`, then zsh will automatically restore terminal options after program exits. `ttyctl` is a zsh builtin, so you cannot use it from bash.

Answer (score 1):

Other folks covered what happened and what to do about it. As to why, the answer to that probably lies in what input Vim received from the xargs command and tried to execute as if that input came from a terminal. I don't know how to talk terminal, but you can imagine that Vim got some strange commands that crashed it or told it to quit. Similarly unpredictable things happen when you cat a binary file.

Anway, I have another idea. Have you tried using vimgrep to browse a list of files matching a pattern?

```
:vimgrep /id="kw"/ *
:copen
```

This greps for `id="kw"` in all files in the current directory. `:copen` opens up a window with a list of matches. You can browse that list, clicking enter to jump to a file position.

[image]

For more information, see

```
:help grep
:help :vimgrep
:help :copen
:help quickfix
```

If you really need that `-I` option, see

```
:help :grep
:help 'grepprg'
```

See also: [Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/96907)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `... | xargs sh -c '...'` and then read from the controlling terminal device `/dev/tty`.

```
echo ~/.profile ~/.bashrc | xargs sh -c 'vim "$@" </dev/tty' dummy_script_name

# based on a tip by Laszlo Ersek on http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2010-03/msg00051.html
#find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs sh -c 'rm -i "$@" </dev/tty' dummy_script_name
```