# Can anyone explain to me what the purpose of /dev/tty

Tags: linux, unix

Can anyone explain what the purpose or how to use /dev/tty

Comment: as an introduction, read this http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: [Link to tty article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/05/50-free-ui-and-web-design-wireframing-kits-resources-and-source-files/)

Comment: Ya i tired that website its kind of confusing. Im wondering if anyone could break it down in simpler terms for a beginner

Answer (score 6):

You can start with the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html).  From there, read about the "controlling terminal" of a process.

But just for example... /dev/tty is how a command like "ssh" can read your password even if its standard input comes from somewhere else:

```
tar cf - . | ssh dest 'tar xf -'
```

If ssh decides to prompt you for a password, it will read it from /dev/tty instead of stdin.

Conceptually, /dev/tty is "the keyboard and text terminal".  More or less.

Answer (score 1):

It allows a program to connect to its "controlling terminal," if any, even if stdin, stdout and stderr have been redirected away from it. A common use is to request a password from the user.

Answer (score 0):

If stdin is already set to be a pipe, you may use /dev/tty to emulate reading from the controlling input terminal device.

For example:

```
echo ~/.profile ~/.bashrc | xargs sh -c 'vim "$@" </dev/tty' dummy_script_name
# :qa  # quit all files
```

See: [After doing grep and passing it to vim then quitting, why am I experiencing this weird console malfunctioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775383/after-doing-grep-and-passing-it-to-vim-then-quitting-why-am-i-experiencing-this)