# How to close the location list after opening an entry from it in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to automatically close the current location list in Vim when the user selects an entry from it, i.e., navigates to a listed location?

The scenario in question is similar to the one in the “[How to open a file in a list of files in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437262/how-to-open-a-file-in-a-list-of-files-in-vim)” question. I have an external program that creates a list of locations (across multiple files) that is then loaded using the `lgetfile` command. When the list is opened, e.g., using the `lopen 10` command, the location list window remains open even after a location is selected.

As an alternative, I would accept any solution that allows me to have a Vim command calling a function with a single argument, based on which an external program is run to write a list of files and locations. I would want to open this list (either in the current or a split window) and be able to select a file (i.e., using <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> for navigation and <kbd>Return</kbd> to select), so that the list is closed and the selected file is opened—much the same as the plugin buffer explorer works, just with a custom list of files instead of the list of buffers.

Maybe there is a (popular and maintained) plugin that could do that for me—perhaps with the added functionality of “Open in a new tab” and “Open in a split window”?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific: how did you open the location list? What you mean by that?

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai - Shooting in the dark here, but I gotta feeling he is using some file manager and it doesn't automatically close when he opens a file/buffer from it.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai:  See `:help location-list` and `:help location-list-window`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can use the following mapping to automatically issue
the `:lclose` command each time <kbd>Return</kbd> is
pressed in the quickfix or location list windows:

```
:autocmd FileType qf nmap <buffer> <cr> <cr>:lcl<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `quickfix` window, and e.g.: `lopen 10`, you can still do `:lopen 10 | lcl`.

And I'd recommend to read [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_to_open_or_close_the_quickfix_window) article in the Vim Wiki(a).

Comment: Doesn't this open and immediately close the quickfix window?

Comment: Yes (almost): `:lopen 10` opens the location list window (not the quickfix window) to a height of 10, and `:lclose` closes it again. I think this was a misread of the question.