# Vim: keep location list window open after selecting a file

Tags: vim

I need exactly the opposite behavior of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846598/close-location-list-when-selecting-file). My observation is that upon pressing `enter` on a line in location list window, the window will be closed and the main window will display the content of the selected file. As a contrary, quickfix window doesn't have this behavior, i.e., it remains opened after the selection.

I have checked my autocmd and there is no special handling for location list or quickfix list.

An example - `:lgrep hi *` to populate the location list. `lopen` to open the location list window. Press `enter` on any line.

Comment: No, neither the location window nor the quickfix window go away when you press `<CR>` on an entry. Try with `$ vim -N`.

Comment: @romainl Why do you want me try vim -N?

Comment: My guess is that you have [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) installed. Is this correct? You may want to tweak `g:syntastic_auto_loc_list` by setting it to `0` in your `vimrc` file. See `:h 'syntastic_auto_loc_list'` for more information.

Comment: @PeterRincker that's correct! If you turn that into an answer I will accept it. Thanks! I can't imagine how I can figure that out by myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Syntastic and the location-list window

[Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) by default closes the location list window when no errors are present. Therefore if you use something like `:lgrep` which does not mark any of the results as errors then the location-list window will close once you leave the location-list window, e.g. like using `<cr>` to jump to a location.

Syntastic provides a way to tweak this via `g:syntastic_auto_loc_list` variable. Setting this to `0` will disable the auto-close functionality.

Set the following in your `vimrc` file:

```
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0
```

To learn more about this variable see: `:h 'syntastic_auto_loc_list'`.

#### Generic Vim debugging

Often the easiest way to test if your `vimrc` or a plugin is causing problem is it compare the functionality to a vanilla vim config (or at least more vanilla). Do this by starting up Vim without a vimrc. I use the following invocation:

```
vim -N -u NONE
```

Once you have started up Vim in this manner you can test for you bug and see if it is present.

- If the bug is still present then it that means it is probably a part of Vim nature or a bug with Vim itself. In this case I suggest you do more read the documentation via `:h :help`, `:h :helpgrep`, and `:h bug-reports`
- If the bug is not present then the error is occurring due to something in your `vimrc` or plugin. This often means you need to disable portions of your vimrc/plugins to try and find the culprit. A fast way is to use a binary search.

#### Slightly more complicated debugging with `:verbose`

Often a bug is easier to track down directly by using `:verbose` to see where something was last set. (See `:h :verbose`)

- Mappings will display were they are last set. e.g. `:verbose nmap <leader>foo`. See `:h :map-verbose` and `:h map-listing`.
- Settings will display where they were last set as well. e.g. `:verbose set shiftwidth`. See `:h :set-verbose`.
- Autocomd's will display where they are last defined. e.g. `:verbose autocmd BufEnter`. See `:h :autocmd-verbose` and `:h autocmd-list`.

#### Advanced debugging with `'verbosefile'`

Another way to debug something is to use `'verbose'`/`:verbose` and `'verbosefile'` to effectively log what Vim is doing.

Example of using `:verbose` and `'verbosefile'` to debug your bug.

- Do `:lgrep` command
- Open location-list window via `:lopen`
- Set `'verbosefile'` via `:set verbosefile=~/verbose.txt`
- `:15verbose normal <c-v><cr>`
- Now open the log file via `:sp ~/verbose.txt`
- Search the log file for anything suspicious. e.g. `close` or `lclose` in your case
- Once found it will show you the `autocmd` or function that is causing the closing.
- If `autocmd` look to revise it.
- If a function you may need to look at `:scriptnames` to figure out which file the is associated with script local functions. See `:scriptnames` and `:h <SID>`.

I find using Tim Pope's [scriptease.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) makes this process easier by providing the `:Verbose` command which will setup `'verbosefile'` for you as well as open it right afterwards in the preview window. Scriptease also provides a nice wrapper around `:scriptnames` via `:Scriptnames`. In general scriptease.vim provides many helpful methods to debugging and reloading plugins.

#### More help

```
:h 'syntastic_auto_loc_list'
:h syntastic
:h -u
:h -N
:h :help
:h :helpgrep
:h bug-reports
:h :map
:h map-listing
:h :set
:h set-option
:h :set-verbose
:h :autocmd-verbose
:h autocmd-list
:h 'verbose'
:h :verbose
:h 'verbosefile'
:h :scriptnames
:h <SID>
:h :normal
:h c_CTRL-V
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort making it an awesome answer!

Comment: Super helpful! I was having the exact same problem and this was a good read.

Comment: I am confused by the `:15verbose normal <c-v><cr>`. When I type <c-v><cr> I just see a ^M at the end of the command mode line. What is supposed to happen here?

Comment: `^M` is a literal `return` button press. See `:h c_CTRL-V`. So `:normal <c-v><cr>` will run `<cr>` in normal mode and is the equivalent of `:execute "normal \<cr>"`, `:call feedkeys("\<cr>", 't')`, or you typing `<cr>` in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use :cw to get quickfix window. It will appear horizontally split to current window.
and :ccl to return back to selected result