# How can I find what VimL functions hook into inserting characters in normal mode?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to get the set of all VimL functions that are called when I type any character in insert mode.

The reason I want this is to find out which is causing Vim to use high CPU when it's trying to complete variables in some cases.

Comment: You can get this information by using `:verbose` & `'verbosefile'` (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32409974/438329)). However, it would be best to know what type of completion you are actually doing. Normal insert-completion, e.g. `<c-n>`/`<c-p>`? or omni-complete? Using some plugin? You may want to take a look at your `'complete'` flags. See `:h 'complete'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`'verbose'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27verbose%27) option controls the logging. With a value of `15` or higher, *any* executed Vim command is logged. As functions can now run asynchronously in the background, or triggered periodically, this gets messy fast, and the hit-enter prompts can prevent you from doing any work. Therefore, it's recommended to redirect the logging into a file by setting [`'verbosefile'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27verbosefile%27) as well.

Comment: Thanks! I found YouCompleteMe stuff running.