# Is there a way for vim to open all .C and .H files in a directory and all its subdirectories?

Tags: vim

I want to execute a substitution in vim on around 20 *.C and *.H files, and I want to open them all at once. All files are distributed in multiple nested directories, and the command is executed in the top parent directory. Can I do this using only vim, or do I need the "find" command and the "-p" option as shown [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437283/735756)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Start Vim at the root of your project:

   ```
   $ vim /path/to/project
   ```
2. Add the relevant files to the arglist, recursively:

   ```
   :argadd **/*.C **/*.H
   ```

   See `:h starstar` and `:h :argadd`.
3. Perform your substitution on every file in the arglist:

   ```
   :argdo s/foo/bar/gc
   ```

   See `:h argdo` and `:h s_flags`.

Comment: I've tried this right now in a test directory, and I get "E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)" error.

Comment: Either `:set hidden` and later save them with `:wall`, or append an `| update` to the `:argdo` command.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed `set hidden`.