# Open muiltiple(100+) files in `gvim` - not in tabs, not in vim

Tags: vim

I'm analyzing a regression of thousands of test cases in linux. So I want to open many files(failed) in `gvim` at once.

I have a file as mention in below with 100+ lines specifying 100+ files in a directory. I want to open all these files in `gvim`(in single `gvim`).

```
./Linux2/Lint/case1/DIFF
./Linux2/Lint/case4/DIFF
./Linux2/Lint/case10/DIFF
./Linux2/range/case1/DIFF
./Linux2/operator/case7/DIFF
```

100+ lines like this.

Is there any way to open files in all these files in `gvim` with some navigation mechanism.

I know it is possible to use,

```
gvim file1 file2 .....
```

But it is not easy with 100+ files.

I need to do this in `gvim`, not in `vim`.

Comment: Not all the DIFF files, But all the DIFF files in failed test cases. Thats why I put those in separate file

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437262/how-to-open-a-file-in-a-list-of-files-in-vim), especially the "quickfix mode" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used `find . -name DIFF | xargs vim` and was able to navigate through all the files using `:next` and `:prev` and `:buffers`

Only ugly bit was when I hit about 1500 files I'd get two invocations of vim and would have to finish editing the first 1500 files before moving on to the next 1500 (Due to the way xargs works).

Another option is to use vims error file parsing. List all the files in an file with information about the line and error, open that file and run `:cbuffer` in that buffer (it will close the error file and move you to the first listed erro). `:copen` will open the list of errors as the *Quickfix List*. Then you can use the usual `:cn` and `:cp` to move between forward and backward in the quickfix list (and `<CR>` in the quickfix list will work too. Something like this should work out of the box for you.

```
:./Linux2/Lint/case1/DIFF:1: Not really an error
:./Linux2/Lint/case2/DIFF:1: Not really an error
:./Linux2/Lint/case3/DIFF:1: Not really an error
```

Now this can be improved since vims error parsing is flexible. You could remove the requirement for the leading `:` by using `set errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m` or just use a raw list of files using `set errorformat=%f`.

Comment: I think the OP already has the names of files he cares about in another file.

Comment: thanks, but my directory have empty DIFF files in PASSED test cases also, I need only to open DIFF files in FAILED test casses

Comment: In that case my second method should work nicely. You could even put some context into the error message about why it failed etc.

Comment: yes, my failed test's diff file contain the reason for fail.

Comment: @Michael Anderson, I ran `:cbuffer` and use `:cn`, `:cp`. It doesn't shows the content of the file. It just display `(3 of 180): file path` at the bottum line of `gvim` window.

Comment: @ANjaNA - I was putting in the error format from memory but got it slightly wrong. It looks like it needs a leading `:` - the application causing the error usually goes before the first `:`. - I've added the leading `:` to the question now, but you could equally change the vim error format string.

Comment: @Michael Anderson, `:copen` opens the list of errors as the Quickfix List. And as you said with `:cn` nad `:cp` i can move around the test cases. But How can I open those test files, Wt I need is **see the content of diff files**

Comment: @ANjaNA - if you're using the list of files where each line is `./Linux2/Lint/case1/DIFF` and you've called `:set errorformat=%f` _before_ running the `:cbuffer` command, then `:cn` should open the DIFF file. If you're using a file where each line is `:./Linux2/Lint/case1/DIFF:1: error` then it will open the DIFF file without you needing to set the `errorformat`.

Comment: @Michael Anderson, it works, What I missed is `:set errorformat=%f` before running the `:cbuffer` command. Thanks

Comment: @Michael Anderson, Imagin I need to go to 15th file directly. Insted of `:cn` 14 times, is there any other way of doing it.

Comment: @ANjaNA select it in the quick-fix window and hit enter? or `:14cn` or `:cc 14`? `:help quickfix` will give pages of options.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to produce a command line argument from a file. You can do that with [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04) in `bash`.

```
gvim $(cat ListOfFiles.txt)
```

Comment: I tried `gvim $(cat failed)` command in bash. Where `failed` is file containing file list. But is gives **Illegal variable name.** error. `cat failed` works fine.